# Grouping in a ListBox bound to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, listbox

I have the following `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1">
  <ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
  </ListBox.GroupStyle>

  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and the code to fill it and to set the grouping:

```
var Addresses = new Dictionary<string, Address>();
Addresses.Add("1", new Address() { State = "xxx", ... });
...
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Addresses);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("State"));
listBox1.ItemsSource = view;
```

I get no grouping, just the items themselves. If I use a `List` instead of the `Dictionary` to fill the `ListBox` with, it works all right but in this particular case, I do need the added functionality of the `Dictionary` (the ability to address the items by key, actually).

Comment: Check for binding errors in the "Output" window. I think `State` can't be resolved. A quick workaround would be to add key to `Address`, then you can use it with linq to mimic `Dictionary`.

Comment: No errors reported. I'll try to find out if adding a converter to the `PropertyGroupDescription` could provide a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Sinatr, this lead me in the right direction. It was actually as simple as:

```
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Value.State"));
```